# list.removeall() is not working appropriately with lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, lambda

```
listCurrentPostsMarkers.RemoveAll(x => 
      listRemoveMarkers.Exists(
          y => y.Position.Latitude == x.Position.Latitude &&
          y.Position.Longitude == x.Position.Longitude));
```

Look, this is not working correctly. I have 1 element in **listRemoveMarkers** and 3 elements in the **listCurrentPostsMarkers** and I want to remove that specific element of **listRemoveMarkers** from **listCurrentPostsMarkers**. But it deletes all the elements from **listCurrentPostsMarkers**. I do not know why?

Comment: Are you sure each element in `listCurrentPostsMarkers` has a unique position? That lambda will remove every marker with the given position, not just the first matching one

Comment: Assuming both `Latitude` and `Longitude` are integer types it is hard to see how this code will fail... Please read [MCVE] guidance and post complete sample, including classes and test data as part of the code.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson You were right. Thanks. I was carrying the same value and problem is on the other previous list.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks man for being so confident that this code will not fail.